# Localhost Registry in Kubernetes - distribute certificates

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running Docker for Mac(Edge) and I have a Kubernetes Cluster.

I am trying to be able to run a Registry inside Kubernetes, so I can push images to the cluster and use them in a Localhost environment.

I have installed a Registry with Helm: `helm install stable/docker-registry`

And I am able to run with portforward:

```
export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app=docker-registry,release=guiding-hedgehog" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 to use your application"
  kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:5000
```

The problem is that I get an error when trying to push to the registry with `docker push localhost:5000/hello`:

```
The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/hello]
Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: dial tcp [::1]:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

kubectl get services:

```
NAME: eyewitness-moose-docker-registry TYPE: ClusterIP CLUSTER-IP:10.106.213.130 EXTERNAL-IP:<none> PORT(S):5000/TCP
```

Note: Also tried adding `docker.for.mac.localhost:5000` to list of insecure registries.

So it looks like a security issue, and might be related to that it is not possible to run an insecure registry described in [Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/)

Therefore I have created a certificate as described [here](http://container-solutions.com/running-secure-registry-kubernetes/).

**Now the question is**, how do I distribute the certificate to each node with only kubectl?

Note: I am running in Docker for Mac(Edge), so I can get to the Kubernetes running containers. But there is so many and how and I don't think that is is the right way:

```
7d50a16271b5        gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller                            "/tiller"                19 hours ago        Up 19 hours                             k8s_tiller_tiller-deploy-865dd6c794-j7nk8_kube-system_8cbf6a09-329d-11e8-83ed-025000000001_0
6c77c450b374        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 19 hours ago        Up 19 hours                             k8s_POD_tiller-deploy-865dd6c794-j7nk8_kube-system_8cbf6a09-329d-11e8-83ed-025000000001_0
ff19b2587142        docker/kube-compose-controller                           "/compose-controller…"   40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_compose_compose-5d4f4d67b6-n9jbp_docker_d7fc0ef4-3065-11e8-b9f8-025000000001_0
22109b6207af        docker/kube-compose-api-server                           "/api-server --kubec…"   40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_compose_compose-api-7bb7b5968f-9mjxr_docker_d7f23906-3065-11e8-b9f8-025000000001_0
fd35236592f2        gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64           "/sidecar --v=2 --lo…"   40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_sidecar_kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-h25hz_kube-system_ba973aaa-3065-11e8-b9f8-025000000001_0
8df955fd61f4        gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64     "/dnsmasq-nanny -v=2…"   40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_dnsmasq_kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-h25hz_kube-system_ba973aaa-3065-11e8-b9f8-025000000001_0
2b35fb82f6e6        gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64          "/kube-dns --domain=…"   40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_kubedns_kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-h25hz_kube-system_ba973aaa-3065-11e8-b9f8-025000000001_0
89b4e3ccccd5        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_POD_compose-5d4f4d67b6-n9jbp_docker_d7fc0ef4-3065-11e8-b9f8-025000000001_0
d5a6a2ba714b        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_POD_kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-h25hz_kube-system_ba973aaa-3065-11e8-b9f8-025000000001_0
608c82a39845        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_POD_compose-api-7bb7b5968f-9mjxr_docker_d7f23906-3065-11e8-b9f8-025000000001_0
38982ea53b7d        gcr.io/google_containers/kube-proxy-amd64                "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-75vvn_kube-system_bace7415-3065-11e8-b9f8-025000000001_0
1e5b99acf1ca        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_POD_kube-proxy-75vvn_kube-system_bace7415-3065-11e8-b9f8-025000000001_0
e75f4b1db79e        gcr.io/google_containers/kube-scheduler-amd64            "kube-scheduler --ku…"   40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler-docker-for-desktop_kube-system_f851ca949bc3883a8c73ea5debfa5def_0
2834798acbc5        gcr.io/google_containers/kube-apiserver-amd64            "kube-apiserver --ad…"   40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-docker-for-desktop_kube-system_caae2ec94c5b9fe55a01978c5b2f561e_0
91cb9c57c7f6        gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64                      "etcd --listen-clien…"   40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_etcd_etcd-docker-for-desktop_kube-system_7278f85057e8bf5cb81c9f96d3b25320_0
ead556edb234        gcr.io/google_containers/kube-controller-manager-amd64   "kube-controller-man…"   40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager-docker-for-desktop_kube-system_81fd91d1cb0957bc579d5dd888f73ead_0
bd4e94136fe5        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_POD_kube-scheduler-docker-for-desktop_kube-system_f851ca949bc3883a8c73ea5debfa5def_0
45f2657c47a7        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_POD_kube-controller-manager-docker-for-desktop_kube-system_81fd91d1cb0957bc579d5dd888f73ead_0
3e5a8064e983        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_POD_etcd-docker-for-desktop_kube-system_7278f85057e8bf5cb81c9f96d3b25320_0
b7ae16f4ce6b        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                 "/pause"                 40 hours ago        Up 40 hours                             k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-docker-for-desktop_kube-system_caae2ec94c5b9fe55a01978c5b2f561e_0
```

Anything in the right direction is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try pushing to 127.0.0.1:5000 rather than localhost:5000. "get sockopt: connection refused" isn't a security error, it means there is nothing listening on the port the connection is being made to. The [::1] is the ipv6 version of localhost- so the localhost name is resolving to the ipv6 interface for localhost, rather than the ipv4 interface for localhost.

Comment: Thanks good suggestion, but I get the same.

Comment: And thanks for pointing out: connection refused" isn't a security error

Comment: Note: kubectl get services: NAME: eyewitness-moose-docker-registry TYPE:  ClusterIP   CLUSTER-IP:10.106.213.130  EXTERNAL-IP:<none>        PORT(S):5000/TCP

Comment: Ah, sorry, it looks like port-forward does both ipv4 and ipv6, but syntax is local-port:remote-port. So that command above is forwarding 127.0.0.1:8080 to the pod's port 5000. Probably just want to use local port 5000.